# fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, flask, keras, python-imaging-library

I am using flask,

In my `config.py` I set this 
`UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Users/kanel/Documents/Developments/upload'`

and controller to handle the file upload.

```
@app.route('/uploaded', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
      print(path)
      model= ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
      img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))
      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      x = preprocess_input(x)
      preds = model.predict(x)
      preds_decoded = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0] 
      print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
      f.save(path)
      return render_template('uploaded.html', title='Success', predictions=preds_decoded, user_image=f.filename)
```

I got this error:

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2766, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kanel/Documents/Developments/upload/chest-example.png'
```

What is wrong with my path? it is say the file not exist , but path is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file doesn't exist in the location you are trying to load it from.
You should save the file to the disk before using PIL to open it up. `f.save(path)` should come before doing `img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))`